# Generate List Of Every Member In The Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im trying to create a list of every member in a server

```
let { guild } = message

Object.values(guild.members).forEach(user => {

   if (user.nickname) console.log(user.nickname.join('\n'))

})
```

All that returns is undefined. How can I generate a list of every member with a nickname then store it into an array?

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Discord.js v12.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
const members = message.guild.members.cache;
const membersWithNames = members.filter(e => e.nickname).array();
const onlyNames = membersWithNames.map(e => e.nickname);
```

Comment: This returns the entire `GuildMember{}` object :(

Comment: This won't work since `GuildMember.nickname` will always return something so `membersWithNames` will be the same as `members`

Comment: That's what I thought aswell, but it states it will return a nickname if the member has a nickname, it doesn't default to username. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=nickname

Comment: @Elitezen you will need to map it and return the nickname value, edited post.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `undefined` because you need to use `cache` to access the Guild's members collection

You need to filter the Guild's members collection by checking if the member's nickname is the same as the member's username

```js
const nicknamedMembers = guild.members.cache.filter((member) => {
  member.nickname !== member.user.username
})
```

Comment: getting an error of `TypeError: guild.members.filter is not a function`

Comment: He forgot `.cache`

Comment: Yeah, my bad, just fixed it

Comment: console returned `Collection [Map] {}` which seems like a good sign, but how do i access the info as an array?

Comment: you can use `.array()` on a collection to make it an array so `...cache.filter().array()`